# Error 26101: SSL certificate common name invalid

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, storage, scvmm

I have 3 systems with similar configuration:

- Windows Server Datacenter 2008R2
- MS System Center 2012
- connected to a storage array

On 2 systems I can add the storage provider from `VMM` without any issues.
On the 3rd system I keep getting this error every time:

```
Storage discovery of provider https://10.10.10.10 at TCPPort 5989 for user admin failed from VMMserver.smis.name.com with error code SSLFailure Failed: SSL certificate common name is invalid. .

Specify valid provider, port and user credentials for storage discovery.

ID: 26101
```

I have updated Windows to the latest updates, including SCVMM rollup 4 and 7.
MS System Center 2012 VMM version 3.0.6062.0
I have double checked the registry key for common name check as described by Microsoft: [How to Add and Classify SMI-S and SMP Storage Devices in VMM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610563.aspx)
I have also removed all the previous certificates.

At this point I have no idea what could cause this SSL failure and how to fix it. I can easily add the provider using the unsecure connection and of course, the other systems show none of these issues.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

### EDIT

I have reinstalled the OS, SQL Server, and SCVMM and the issue persists. This time I have not installed any of the updates.
The only thing that I noticed, which doesn't seem to be the issue, when installing the SCVMM, it doesn't accept port 1433. The installation works without a port number.

### EDIT 2

It seems that during the discovery process, even though it is not supposed to check the certificate common name, it is still being checked and failed.
How can I force disable the check, having in consideration the registry key is set to not check?

```
DisableHttpsCommonNameCheck = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by this registry key, `DisableHttpsCommonNameCheck`, which was of the wrong type. It should be of type `DWORD (32-bit)` with the value set to 1.
In my case, the key had the wrong type, a string value.